# If command in Batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, echo

I am wondering why my code works this way:

```
If exist c:\work\first\food.txt (echo win) else (echo fail)
```

but not like this:

```
If exist c:\work\first\food.txt (echo food.txt is in C:\work\first) else (echo fail)
```

I'm using Notepad++ to write this and "in" and `c:\work\first` are highlighted blue like the other commands if that helps.

Comment: woops just figured it out I gotta use the ^ symbol after in

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.  There is no need to escape anything in that particular line.

However double quotes are needed in several cases - where spaces are in the path or & characters etc.

```
If exist "c:\work\first\food.txt" (echo food.txt is in C:\work\first) else (echo fail)
```